# Whether a specific function parameter annotated?

Tags: java, annotations

How to determine whether method has an annotated parameter?

Let we have Param `@interface`

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Param {
    public String value() default "";
}
```

and MyClass class

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void method(@Param("param") String p){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

I need to check `MyClass.method` for annotated parameter programmatically.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterAnnotations%28%29

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, I've understood.